# p.join() in Python 2

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need this result :

```
t0 = core 0 Loaded with process 0
t1 = core 1 Loaded with process 1
t2 = core 2 Loaded with process 2
t3 = core 0 Free // a serial processing for each core
t4 = core 0 Loaded with process 3
t5 = core core 1 Free
.... according process 0,1,2,3 takes, in theory the same time on any core
```

Without `p.join()` I get :

```
t0 = core 0 Loaded with process 0
t1 = core 1 Loaded with process 1
t2 = core 2 Loaded with process 2
t4 = core 0 Loaded with process 3 // two process on core 0
t5 = core 1 Loaded with process 4 // etc etc ...
```

With `p.join()` I get :

```
t0 = core 0 Loaded with process 0
t1 = core 0 Free // that is not multiprocessing ...
t2 = core 1 Loaded with process 1
t3 = core 1 Free
t4 = core 2 Loaded with process 2
t5 = core 2 Free
```

I'm seeking a `if !p.busy()` ... like or whatever.
The purpose is to transform a single process image resizing programm into a multiprocess one.

`p.join()` comes from

```
p = Process(target=fonction, args=((process_id),filearg[file],t0))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: What is the `p` in `p.join()`? Are you spawning the processes one by one using `subprocess.Popen`(or similar), or is `p` a `multiprocessing.Pool` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask is *impossible*. Python and its modules do **not** handle scheduling. That's completely up to the OS. If the OS thinks it is better to use core X for a certain process than it will use it. Period.

The best you can do is to change the CPU affinity of a process. You can do this using the [`psutil`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library, in particular with the `set_cpu_affinity` function.

Note that, depending on the OS and the scheduler affinity might or might not be always enforced(i.e. you may set the affinity in some way, but the OS disregards it in some situations).

---

To set the cpu affinity with `multiprocessing`'s `Process` instances you can do:

```
processes = []
for i in range(4):
    p = Process(target=fonction, args=((process_id),filearg[file],t0))
    p.start()
    proc = psutil.Process(p.pid)
    proc.set_cpu_affinity([i])
    processes.append(p)

# Wait for *all* the child processes to terminate.
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

If you want to repeatedly spawn processes when the CPUs are free you can do something like:

```
processes = []
for i in range(4):
    p = Process(target=fonction, args=((process_id),filearg[file],t0))
    p.start()
    proc = psutil.Process(p.pid)
    proc.set_cpu_affinity([i])
    processes.append(p)

while True:
    for i, p in enumerate(processes):
        if not p.is_alive():
            # this process finished. Replace with a new one.
            p.join()
            new_p = Process(...)
            new_p.start()
            proc = psutil.Process(new_p.pid)
            proc.set_cpu_affinity([i])
            processes[i] = new_p
```

Try to play a bit with this kind of code and you should be able to achieve, *almost* the output you want.

Comment: OK. I totally agree. You can read **slot** or **boxes** instead of cores. I mean, if I load 1 slot, the OS will give it to one core (first free I guess, and i do not matter), I want to load MAX_PROCESSOR slots, one, then another one, then ... And reload the first **slot** when it has finished the function. I Want to parallelize a function on 2 or more instances, but i want to name thoses instance, like inst(0), inst(1), inst(2) and let inst(0) be serialize for itself. Perhaps i'm not so clear. Sorry for my relative English :)

Comment: So Bekuriu, could you replace each terms of cores and process by their real meaning in reality ? Perhaps process 0 loaded with function 1 for example ?

Comment: Great answer, Great Guy ! I though about **if p.busy** or someting ! :) I'm affraid about the enumeration. It cost a loop that is switching quite rapidly. Is it a good Idea to switch between p in _enumerate_ with a **time.sleep(x)** ?

Comment: @mat.viguier Probably yes. I just coded as simple as possible. If you don't want to keep the CPU busy you can add a `time.sleep()` call. A more complex solution could be to have a `multiprocessing.Queue` shared between the processes. When a subprocess terminates it puts an object in the queue. Instead of the call to `time.sleep(x)` you can then use `output_queue.get()`, which blocks until something is sent. In this way the loop is executed *only* when there are processes to replace[but you must be careful to avoid deadlocks and race conditions]

Comment: @mat.viguier If you use `time.sleep()` you are fine. With more complicated solutions using queues then you must be careful to avoid deadlocks(i.e. the problems blocks forever without doing nothing). But in your case using `time.sleep()` should be fine.